# Regex to replace characters inside a string

Tags: regex, notepad++

What regex should I use in Notepad++ to replace all the `?` in the following string? Target string is made by all the characters after `/` and before `.jpg`?

```
example.com/longtext?longtext.jpg
example.com/anothertext?anothertext.jpg
example.com/text?text.jpg
...
```

What regex would you use to replace `?` with `_` ?

Comment: You got a half-answer. But in order to really help you: tell the the programming language you intend to use. You see, that affects how you would use a regex in order to do string manipulation.

Comment: I use Notepad++

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(/[^/]+)\?(?=.+?\.jpg)`
- Replace with: `$1_`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: Invalid regular expression -> error message

Comment: @GingerGirl: Lookbehind doesn't work fine in Npp, see my edit, I use now a capture group.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a regular expression here.

You are looking for a single character "?"; and you want to replace that with "_". That is a simple "this for that" replace that most languages can handle **without** the need to turn to regular expressions.

Comment: the text is inside a big file. If I use find and replace, it will replace other lines that don't need to be touched.

I want a regex to apply this rule to these lines only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression. It uses a positive lookahead to select all `?`, which are followed by the pattern inside `(?=)`. The selector of the characters in between the question mark and `.jpg` has a non greedy quantifier `*?` which allows for multiple replacements inside one string. The searched element will also be in the matching group $1:

```
(\?)(?=.*?\.jpg\b)
```

To match all occurences, you need to use a language specific function or the flag `/g`:

```
/(\?)(?=.*?\.jpg\b)/g
```

Comment: It finds all ? in the full document. I want to get only the ones between / and .jpg (there are no spaces) @ssc-hrep3